# ApachePulsar: How to get policies of namespace "sample/standalone/ns1"?

Tags: apache-pulsar

I'm working with Pulsar Admin Rest API and want to get policies of a namespace with API from the docs: 
`/admin/v2/namespaces/{tenant}/{namespace}`

Pulsar have 2 default tenants: public, sample. From that, I've got:

- `public`: `public/default`, `public/functions`.
- `sample`: `sample/standalone/ns1`.

We can understand that in `public/default`: namespace name is `default`, tenant is `public`.

The problem is with `sample/standalone/ns1`, the tenant is `sample` and namespace is `standalone/ns1` is the name, isn't it? If so, how can I get policies from that?

I tried above API `/admin/v2/namespaces/sample/standalone/ns1` but got `405: Method not Allowed`

I hope someone can explain me this issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I think there might be some confusion in there as `standalone` is mostlikle the name of the cluster. This cluster name is usually created when you run the Pulsar in standalone mode.

Also, if you need to get the policies of the namespace `ns1` that is in the `sample` tenant, you would need to run a request against the following URL:

```
/admin/v2/namespaces/sample/ns1
```

Please note that `namespaces` in the above URL is referring to endpoint to work with the namespace resources, and it has nothing to do with naming.